# I am getting random number when giving no. > 55

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

- C language
- bubble sorting by using pointer
- I am using CodeBlocks IDE

I am getting a problem that when I am giving inputs more than 55, it is giving me as output some random number, but only for largest (greater than 55).

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>


void input(int * p) {
  int i;
  printf("Enter 5 numbers");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    scanf("%d", p + i);
}

void display(int * p) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("\n%d", *(p + i));
}

void sort(int * p) {
  int r, t, i;
  for (r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 5 - r; i++) {
      if ( * (p + i) > * (p + i + 1)) {
        t = * (p + i);
        *(p + i) = * (p + i + 1);
        *(p + i + 1) = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
void main() {
  int a[5];
  input(a);
  display(a);
  sort(a);
  display(a);
  getch();
}
```

Input to above code :

```
Enter 5 numbers 2
43
65
12
5
```

Output :

```
2
43
65
12
5


2  
5
12
28
43
```

Comment: Please indent your code. Just like the samples in your beginner's C text book. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: Also please explain what the program is supposed to do and show a sample of input and expecded vs actual output.

Comment: Thanks for advising me. I will keep all above things in my mind next time while asking any question.

Answer (score 1):

In your `sort` function, the first run through the inner loop (ie. for `r == 0`) :

```
for (i = 0; i < 5 - r; i++) {
```

will iterate between `i = 0` and `i = 4` (included).

In the loop body, you check the value at index `i` against the value at index `i + 1` :

```
  if ( * (p + i) > * (p + i + 1)) {
```

But when `i = 4`, that means `i + 1 == 5`. `5` is not a valid index in the provided array (which only holds 5 values, so index `4` is the last).

This means you invoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

To fix it, simply do :

```
for (i = 0; i < 4 - r; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I got the point.